# Google Play Store total size for uploading app

Tags: android, google-play, quota

As far I know, there is an upload limit (15 apps per day) at google play store.
My question: Is there any total size/storage limit at google play store just like gmail has 15 GB total storage?

Comment: [The info is here and it appears not.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2481797?hl=en-GB) 100mb limit for app, use expansion files up to 2Gb each to add more. There appears to be no limit to how many expansion files you can have.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of [this](https://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html) document it's stated that the max APK supported size is 100MB.
Using an expansion file, you can add 2GB more data to your APK.
There is a limit for a maximum of 2 expansion file per app, pushing the limit to 4.1GB total (theorically)

I think nobody had hit the Google Play max developers console space size for apps (if exists)